# Doorbell transformer is this it?

Tags: nest, transformer, doorbell

I am going nuts trying to find my doorbell transformer.  Someone suggested it may be this.  But doesn't look like one to me. Is it?  If not any suggestions where it may be?

[image]

Comment: Fundamental, but have you traced the wire from the push switch and/or the bell itself back to wherever it goes?

Answer (score 26):

As indicated by Ecnerwal the picture you show is an old style telephone line hookup. When you go looking around for your doorbell transformer it may look like one of these:

Mounted on cover of an electrical junction box similar to the following. Liable to be found in garage or basement fairly close in distance to the bell button and bell unit.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.ringdoorbellinstallationguy.com/transformer-installation/doorbell-transformer-replacement/)*</sup>

Mounted to side of a ceiling light fixture junction box in garage or basement:

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.gardenfork.tv/replaced-doorbell/)*</sup>

Mounted on the side of the service entrance box / distribution panel.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/86038/can-a-doorbell-transformer-sit-loose-inside-main-panel)*</sup>

Mounted in some obscure place in your attic on a junction box.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/123531/what-is-this-thing-on-my-junction-box)*</sup>

And finally it is possible that you may find a plug-in style door bell transformer that is secured to some electrical receptacle someplace. One would look similar to this.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.absoluteautomation.com/dsc-ptd1640u-plug-in-power-transformer-16vac-40va/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIq-zIgJ6t6AIVkq_sCh0dcQ0cEAQYAyABEgJrZ_D_BwE)*</sup>

Comment: Very comprehensive!

Comment: You forgot BEHIND THE BELL ITSELF.  Bells are usually sticking out beyond the surface of thewall for aesthetic or decorative reasons.  During frame in sometimes they put a junction box in the wall behind where the bell will go to hold the wire.  That's certainly how they do most of the wires.  And after the drywall's up that box would be wasted space if they didn't put the transformer in it.  That's how my house is.

Answer (score 18):

Nope. That's a phone line terminal block. Old school. May have rudimentary surge supression built in. The heavy black wire is drop cable (from the pole to your house)

It's **not** your doorbell transformer.

Comment: ayup http://www.classicrotaryphones.com/forum/index.php?topic=416.0

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is inside the electrical panel even though it is not supposed to be in there. I have found them inside the electrical panel many times.